# SupportAssistWire.exe - This application could not be started

Tags: .net

[image: 1]

This keeps on showing up. I tried to install it already, but it didn't stop to pop up on my window.

Comment: hi, your question might need some more context, but infering from the error message I would say you need to install .net framework 4.7.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about tech support.